# XMLHttpRequest cannot load error

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, ajax

i am calling web service published on azure site from office 365 it gives me following error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://azuresite.azurewebsites.net/CrmData.svc/AccountSet. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://office365site.sharepoint.com' is therefore not allowed access.

My Code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://azuresite.azurewebsites.net/CrmData.svc/AccountSet",
    async: false,
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        showItems(data);
    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Browser is not allowing you to access service which is published on different domain.

following is link of tutorial of how to access cross domain service.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/